# How to show a pop up like ringer/volume pop up in iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, popup

There is a toggle `UISwitch` in my iOS app. I want to show a pop up with some image similar to the one presented when volume buttons are pressed or silent button is turned on/off in iPhone.

I was searching through iOS development sites/blogs and Apple iOS documentation but could not find anything.

How can i do that? Which view controller class provides such implementation?

Comment: none. look at cocoa controls or github to find something similar. start with custom alerts / activity indication / progress huds

Comment: MBProgressHUD is a good open source project for stuff like this.  https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

Comment: Thanks much !! @DavidShaw . At least i got to know what it is called and some clue about it so that i can further research and analyze to implement.

Comment: Thanks @Wain for throwing some light about what it really is a HUD.